# Safari Develop cannot view Cordova app after xcode9/ios11

Tags: xcode, cordova, debugging, safari, ios11

After the release of iOS 11, I try to update all the development tools in mac. I updated macOS, Xcode and iPhone iOS version to latest.

After that, the safari develop cannot display the Cordova app anymore. I have been reset safari setting/ iPhone setting for running the debug mode.

**How can I using the safari debug cordova app again?**
**(iPhone opened the safari advance function & Safari opened the develop menu)**

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

After update the iOS version, you also need to update the develop beta safari version (maybe not public yet).

Update your safari in: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/